# Ticket change available

Tags: c#

I got a homework to do in csharp:

**The new "Avengers" movie has just been released!
There are a lot of people at the cinema box office standing in a huge line. Each of them has a single 100, 50 or 25 dollar bill. An "Avengers" ticket costs 25 dollars.**

**Vasya is currently working as a clerk. He wants to sell a ticket to every single person in this line.
Can Vasya sell a ticket to every person and give change if he initially has no money and sells the tickets strictly in the order people queue?**

**Return YES, if Vasya can sell a ticket to every person and give change with the bills he has at hand at that moment. Otherwise return NO.**

My code so far is

```
using System;

public class Line
{
    public static string Tickets(int[] q) //queue of people
    { 
      int tf = 0; //twentyfive dollar bill
      int f = 0; //fifty dollar bill
      int h = 0; //hundred dollar bill
      for(int i=0; i < q.Length; i++) {
        if(q[i] == 25) {
          tf++;
        }
        else if(q[i] == 50 && tf >= 1) {
          tf--;
          f++;
        }
        else if(q[i] == 100 && tf == 1 && f == 1) {
          h++;
          tf--;
          f--;
        }
        else if(q[i] == 100 && tf == 3 && f == 0) {
          h++;
          tf = tf - 3;
        }
        else return "NO";
      }
      return "YES";
    }
}
```

And I have passed 16/17 tests (test 6 somehow, the queue is in the comments), but I don't know what was the queue of people in that one test.
Does anyone see a mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Test 6 should be 25,25,25,25,50,100,50

Comment: For your change-from-100s lines, you just need at least that number of notes not exactly that number. Like the tfs in the 50 line. As it stands once you have two 50 notes you won't give anyone change from 100.

Comment: ^^ That's why in Test 6, you have 4 tf, then 3tf+1f, then it checks for 100 and none of the cases match, because you test for _exactly_ 1tf+1f or 3tf+0f ...

Comment: But you can give change back if you have exactly 3tf OR 1tf and 1f

Comment: No, if I have 10tf I can still give 3tf change and have 7tf left. I don't have to give away all of my money. You can give change if you have at least 3tf, or at least one f and at least one tf.

Comment: Its the morning programming.. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your second `if else condition` to `tf >=1 && f >=1` this will check if you have one twenty five or more and fifty one or more

```
public static string Tickets(int[] q) //queue of people
    { 
      int tf = 0; //twentyfive dollar bill
      int f = 0; //fifty dollar bill
      int h = 0; //hundred dollar bill
      for(int i=0; i < q.Length; i++) {
        if(q[i] == 25) {
          tf++;
        }
        else if(q[i] == 50 && tf >= 1) {
          tf--;
          f++;
        }
        else if(q[i] == 100 && tf >= 1 && f >= 1) {
          h++;
          tf--;
          f--;
        }
        else if(q[i] == 100 && tf >= 3 && f == 0) {
          h++;
          tf = tf - 3;
        }
        else return "NO";
      }
      return "YES";
    }
```